# Injecting class dynamically based on request using Unity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am using developing an MVC4 application using Unity. My architecture is like this.

```
public interface IRepositoy<T>
{
}

public class DataRepository<T>:IRepository
{
}
```

Basically here T is Model.

Then again

```
 public interface IModel
 {
 //Property and methods
 }

public class Mobile: IModel
```

All the model classes inherit from this interface.

Now in unity I am using the following syntax

```
RegisterType<IRepository<Mobile>, DataRepository<Mobile>>();
```

and here is the problem.

I want this "Mobile" class to be dependent on the request URL. say mobile page is request "Mobile" class will be injected, if "Camera" page is requested camera object will be injected.

I could do this using if-else. but i am looking for more sophisticated way that will make code more maintainable and robust. I am new to Unity and DI so don't know the best way.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking at it the wrong way.

All you need is a product controller in that case. Your base class entity would be Product and then you'd inherit from that class in your model for stuff like like Mobile, Desktop or what not. Check EF inheritance:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i have done. but i need to feed the inherited class(mobile,desktop) to the product controller so that it can serve particular type of request. Any suggestion how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Look into dependency injection through IoC. Basically, you can say I want an IRepository of type Mobile to be injected into my MobileController:

```
public MobileController(IRepository<Mobile> repo) {}
```

But, when I use my PersonController, I want an IRepository or type Person:

```
public PersonController(IRepository<Person> repo) {}
```

Then using IoC, you can register all your dependencies. So you can say, if a controller ever asks for an IRepository of type Mobile, give them a DataRepository of type Mobile, but if a controller asks for an IRepository of type Person, give them a DataRepository of type Person. Ninject and AutoFac are two popular choices. Setting up Ninject looks like:

```
Bind<IRepository<Mobile>>().To<DataRepository<Mobile>>();
Bind<IRepository<Person>>().To<DataRepository<Person>>();
```

Register Ninject in your AppStart and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my architecture is little bit different.. What is have is generic controller like
    pulic ProductController(IRepository<T> repo) {}
So i am thinking of anything can be done inspecting URL to determine which model should be injected.